# System.Diagnostics in VB Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is it at all possible to reference System.Diagnostics in VB Excel? When I go to Tools > References and browse to the .NET 4 folders, I can't add a reference to the System.dll file as I get an error and I don't see the System.Diagnostics either. I need to be able to use System.Diagnostics.Process in my code.

Comment: Any other information that might help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

it is there for me. You can use the browse button and search for system.dll

Comment: Yup, I have apparently got that ticked in the list, but I still get an error returned when using the Process type, any ideas?

Comment: Compile error:
User-defined type not defined

It highlights the following: Dim proc() As Process

Comment: did you check and make sure it is in the object browser?

Comment: It's not in the object browser, thank you for pointing me to this view, I wasn't aware of it in vba excel. I can select the system reference but the process type isn't listed. I need to get system.diagnostics referenced. This is very confusing! :(

Comment: can you create a class library in Visual Studio and import it into VBA editor?

Comment: I know roughly the process involved in this but how would I recreate the process class in this library that is to be imported? Sorry for this..